# Unity : from Asset Bundles to On Demand Resources

Tags: unity-game-engine, assetbundle, on-demand-resources

I'm currently looking to implement On Demand Resource on my project.
I already use Asset Bundle, but I'd want some of them to be On Demand Resource.

I found this page https://docs.unity3d.com/2019.4/Documentation/Manual/AppThinning.html

And there is things that I'm not sure to understand.
So I need to create a script BuildiOSAssetBundles to tell Unity which Asset Bundle I want to use as ODR.
But I'm confuse by this line :

```
new UnityEditor.iOS.Resource( "bundle", "Assets/Bundles/bundle.unity3d" ).AddOnDemandResourceTags("bundle"),
```

I didn't found the documentation of "Unity.iOS.Resource" object, and I'm a bit confused about the path I should give.
For exemple, I have a bundle named "foo/bar", which is composed of 3 scenes : "foo_level1", "foo_level2", and "foo_level3", let's say that theses scenes are located in a folder named "Assets/Foo/Scenes".

How do i do to tell Unity that this bundle should be a On Demand Resource ?
Plus, I have a lot of bundle similar to "foo/bar" (let's say 50). Do I have to register them one by one in that script ? Or is there a way to "mark" every bundle starting with "foo/" as ODR ? (Is there a GUI ?)

When I build my assets bundles from the GUI, the path I'm using is "AssetBundles/iOS". May be I should use that in the path ?